# TcpListener : Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

what is the solution to fix "**Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted**" error in .net while starting TcpListener.

Comment: You can only have one Listener listening to a port number.  A TcpListener will allow more than one client to connect at the port number.  You do not need to open a second Listener.  When more than one client connects you should use the async method.  You could be getting the error because another app is alrady using the port number.  To find out if the port is being used from cmd.exe type following >Netstat -a

Comment: @jdweng how to fix this exception?

Comment: Do not open more than one Listener for a port number, or make sure you close/dispose the listener using the port before opening a new listener.

Comment: the question is why do you think you need a second listener on that port?

Answer (score 2):

As other users in comments said

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

error occurs when you already have TcpListener opened on specified port, be it your listener or other application.
As @jdweng said, to find out if the port is being used from cmd.exe type following >Netstat -a.

Also, in addition to netstat, you can use [TCPview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) program which shows all ports currently in use and shows which process uses them.

Comment: For the record `netstat -ano` (for example) will also show the process id associated with each socket handle. Task Manager can then be used to identify the process further, if needed. I often do something like `netstat -ano | find "xxxx" ` to quickly identify whether port xxxx is in use and by whom.